How to bake the cast modifier effect on my mesh?
I'm using a cast modifier to simulate a dinosaur gulping food, here's a gif of the effect:

The thing is that I want to import this as an animation to a game engine (Godot) and for the love of me, I can't find the way to do it. I tried applying as shape keys, but the shape key does nothing.
Am I missing something or I can't do this?
Thanks a lot!

Does this answer solve your question? If not, please [edit] your question to further explain your situation, how this answer doesn't help your case, maybe even share your file.
